"The same hated one"?

"And so Tully, relating the story of his marriage, crawled through the afternoon, separating nuts from clods until all nuts were the same hated one thrown forever into the bucket."

Does it mean when he separated walnuts from clods and put them beside each other ,then all of them looked like a big one (a pile of them) and that caused him fellings of hatered, agony and etc?
By the way, He is a retired boxer who works as a farm worker ,and his work is so hard and excruciating.

What is the source of your quote?

@RonaldSole Fat City by Leonard Gardner

Your reading is close, but more likely is "he did the same thing so many times that it stopped feeling like many actions and just felt like he was throwing the exact same nut in the exact same bucket forever."
That is, in "until all nuts were the same hated one," the "were" is metaphorical, and really means "seemed like."

thank you so much.  Can I rephrase it like this? Until all nuts seemed like the preceding disgusting/ugly/damned one that was in the bucket forever.

@SoroushGh I suppose that's pretty similar
